Player moves but the custom bloxy cola can does not
The script moves the player not the item, it should work like a bloxy cola, this is the script:
local Tool = script.Parent;

enabled = true




function onActivated()
    if not enabled  then
        return
    end

    enabled = false
    Tool.GripForward = Vector3.new(0,-.759,-.651)
    Tool.GripPos = Vector3.new(1.5,-.5,.3)
    Tool.GripRight = Vector3.new(1,0,0)
    Tool.GripUp = Vector3.new(0,.651,-.759)


    Tool.Handle.DrinkSound:Play()

    wait(3)
    
    local h = Tool.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if (h ~= nil) then
        if (h.MaxHealth > h.Health + 5) then
            h.Health = h.Health + 5
        else    
            h.Health = h.MaxHealth
        end
    end

    Tool.GripForward = Vector3.new(-.976,0,-0.217)
    Tool.GripPos = Vector3.new(0.03,0,0)
    Tool.GripRight = Vector3.new(.217,0,-.976)
    Tool.GripUp = Vector3.new(0,1,0)

    enabled = true

end

function onEquipped()
    Tool.Handle.OpenSound:play()
end

script.Parent.Activated:connect(onActivated)
script.Parent.Equipped:connect(onEquipped)

Here is a screenshot of the can tool :

it should work like a regular bloxy cola.
